# Spark rename dataframe columns weird behavior

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I've encountered an odd behavior when trying to rename a dataframe columns.

I've got two vals, `fail` and `ok`, each representing exactly the same list.

```
scala> fail
res136: Array[String] = Array(en, vi, ro, ur, lv, pl, pt, tl, in, ko, uk, cs, sr, tr, de, is, es, eu, el, it, ar, nl, bn, hu, iw, th, lt, no, fa, bg, cy, hi, et, zh, fr)

scala> ok
res137: Array[String] = Array(en, vi, ro, ur, lv, pl, pt, tl, in, ko, uk, cs, sr, tr, de, is, es, eu, el, it, ar, nl, bn, hu, iw, th, lt, no, fa, bg, cy, hi, et, zh, fr)

scala> fail.deep == ok.deep && fail.getClass == ok.getClass
res145: Boolean = true
```

The thing is, I began to question my sanity when I tried the following :

```
scala> cross.toDF("y"+:fail:_*).count
res142: Long = 1

scala> cross.toDF("y"+:ok:_*).count
res143: Long = 41
```

Plus, that :

```
scala> val exactlyTheSameDF = cross
exactlyTheSameDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [y_prediction: string, 0.0: bigint ... 34 more fields]

scala> exactlyTheSameDF.toDF("y"+:ok:_*).count
res150: Long = 41

scala> exactlyTheSameDF.toDF("y"+:fail:_*).count
res151: Long = 41
```

There must be something I missed, any idea ?

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this. What is "cross"? If it's an RDD/DF can you share the columns?

Comment: Hi, "cross" is a dataframe obtained from the crosstab func. The columns are just representing languages with a float (e.g :  0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,...) that's why I tried to map them to their respective name